# How significant was the contribution of crime rate on the breakup of the USSR?

Tags: russian-federation, communism, soviet-union

For the generation born in the 1970s in the USSR it was not uncommon to have nearly all of the classmates to be imprisoned for various crimes either during the school years or shortly thereafter. [This excellent answer](http://qr.ae/RbrYJY) by Sergey Zubkov, an author of some books on programming describes the situation quite well. I also have first-hand accounts, my relatives and other people I know also said that nearly all the class where they were studying was eventually imprisoned. The crimes were usually murders, robberies, making heavy injuries, beatings to death etc.

When I was studying in the 1980s/1990s the situation was quite similar. I speculate that this is not the case of other counties (I may be wrong, so correct me).

I wonder what share in the eventual breakup of the USSR belongs to this amount of crime. Was not it one of the major causes? I suspect that there is nothing similar in North Korea, and that country still has Communist government.

Comment: Breakup of USSR had mostly to do with the conflation of mutual desires of "socialist" Republics to be independent, of current USSR leadership to get Western technology and investments to prop up failing economy, and of Western side being interested in that breakdown to ensure USSR/Russia was not threatening Europe. The crime was a factor as far as being a drag on economy, but not the main one.

Comment: Also, I'm prety sure "all people" from a class being incarcerated is a great exaggregation. My class was what Americans would call "ghetto" or "inner city" gang culture demographics, and only a few people were incarcerated by the time I graduated college - probably no more than 30%. Likely less. Look at US incarceration rate for comparison

Comment: @user4012  what is US rate?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_incarceration_rate

Comment: @user4012 this is mostly because of longer terms. Russia is close by the number of prisoners https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_incarceration_rate#/media/File:Incarceration_rates_worldwide.gif but they have A LOT shorter terms with intentional murder usually amounts for no more than 6-8 years and prisoners released when a half of the term completed. Thy also usually do not add terms if a person commited several crimes.

Comment: Crime is generally a symptom of a poor economy- this is what causes a collapse of a system.  Crime is merely a result of this, and not a cause of change in a society.